# How to stop recomposition of items using same data class whose values have not changed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

So  I am creating a app in jetpack compose that has lot's TextFields(50+) in one composable.

I am using using a data class to store values of this Texfields.

Data classes:

```kotlin
data class FormField(
val value:String = "",
val error: String = "",
val isRequired: Boolean = false,
)


data class FormData(

val firstName: FormField = FormField(),
val lastName: FormField = FormField(),
val middleName: FormField = FormField(),
)
```

My viewModel:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _formData  = mutableStateOf(FormData())

val formData:State<FormData> = _formData

fun setFormData(newValues:FormData){

_formData.value = newValues

}

}
```

My composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun mycomposable(vm:MyViewModel){

OutlinedTextFiled(value = vm.formData.firstName, onValueChanged = {  vm.setFormData(vm.formData.copy(firstName = it)) })

OutlinedTextFiled(value = vm.formData.lastName, onValueChanged = {  vm.setFormData(vm.formData.copy(lastName = it)) })

OutlinedTextFiled(value = vm.formData.middleName, onValueChanged = {  vm.setFormData(vm.formData.copy(middleName = it)) })

}
```

Now the problem is when I type into one of the fields all other fields are being recomposed too. The form being large enough produces jank on low end devices.

So far I have tried use derivedStateOf like:

```
val firstName by remember { derivedStateOf(vm.formData.firstName) } }

val lastName by remember { derivedStateOf(vm.formData.lastName) } }

val middleName by remember { derivedStateOf(vm.formData.middleName) } }
```

But this result in the values not updating at all and even if it worked I dont think this would scale well.

Comment: https://blog.shreyaspatil.dev/leveraging-the-snapshot-mutation-policies-of-jetpack-compose using snapshot mutation policy.